# Selecting Values from different arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Let's pretend I have two arrays.

```
0: Array[4]
0: "STNAME"
1: "POP"
2: "DATE"
3: "state"
length: 4
```

and

```
2: Array[4]
0: "Alabama"
1: "4833722"
2: "6"
3: "01"
```

I want to select the the 3rd value in the 2nd array. Nothing that I am doing seems to be working . . . what is a good approach for doing this?

Comment: array[2].[2] didn't work and neither did array[2].array[2], what do you suggest?

Comment: it should be `array[2][2]` not `array[2].[2]`

Comment: If you would have posted that as an answer instead of a comment, I'd have marked this as solved :P That did the trick, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should be use array[2][2] and not array[2].[2].

Comment: Although someone else already posted this, since I can't mark his comment as "Solved," I'm going to mark this one as solved, even though Anik Islam Abhi answered it first.

Comment: Thanks, i did not see the previous comment!